# how to tokenize the particular string with AND and OR conditions

Tags: java

from JSP below Category string will passed;How to compare the Category with the Category that is stored in Hashtable key and replace with the values?

For example if Category comes as "Entire Category AND Full-Res PDF PDF (print)" then final output should as "900014 AND 724242"

if another Category comes as "(Composite Pattern AND Cover) OR (Full-Res PDF (print) AND Cover)" then final output should as "(36363636 AND 7697979) OR (724242 AND 7697979) "

```
1.Entire Category AND Full-Res PDF PDF (print)
2.Cover Image OR (Full-Res PDF (print) AND Entire Category)
3.Composite Pattern OR Full-Res PDF (print)
4.(Composite Pattern AND Cover) OR (Full-Res PDF (print) AND Cover)
```

Category and the value will be stored in the Hashtable.

```
hashtable.put("Entire Category","900014");
hashtable.put("Full-Res PDF PDF (print)","724242");
hashtable.put("Composite Pattern","36363636");
hashtable.put("Entire Category","352525");
hashtable.put("Cover Image","95757");
hashtable.put("Cover","7697979");
```

Comment: You mean creating an SQL query like string? Where do you get the inputs?

Comment: yes;from JSP I will pass category as (Composite Pattern AND Cover) OR (Full-Res PDF (print) AND Cover) then in SERVLET need to replace with category values compare with those catgories stored in hashtable and finally need to generate sql query

Comment: I'm working right now, but if within lunch time nobody will have written an answer, I'll write mine (1h:30m)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Map<String,String> hashtable = new Hashtable<>();
hashtable.put("Entire Category","900014");
hashtable.put("Full-Res PDF PDF (print)","724242");
hashtable.put("Composite Pattern","36363636");
hashtable.put("Entire Category","352525");
hashtable.put("Cover Image","95757");
hashtable.put("Cover","7697979");

String s = "Entire Category AND Full-Res PDF PDF (print)";

foreach(Map.Entry<String, String> m : hashtable.entrySet())
    while(s.contains(string.getKey()))
            s= s.replace(string.getKey(), string.getValue());
```

Please remember to mark as answer

Comment: its not working.output is coming as string only "Entire Category AND Full-Res PDF PDF (print)"

Comment: it is replaceAll. I hoped it worked, but it didn't. edited to have the new code `while(s.contains(string.getKey()))
    s= s.replace(string.getKey(), string.getValue());`

Comment: @user739115 although, you have a duplicate key there!

Comment: sorry by mistake,duplicate key came;